# Selenium 2.0 Remote web driver fails to start IEDriver with C#

Tags: c#, selenium

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer();
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("webdriver.ie.driver", @"C:\\IEDriverServer.exe");
instance = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

I also have the a system variable set, and the `IEDriverServer` is in the system path. I cannot run the IEDriver from command line (which makes me thinking is there something wrong with path configuration, or  some security restriction)

note that the hub and the node are one and the same machine.

when I execute the test I get:

```
"System.InvalidOperationException: 
The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property; for m....."![enter image description here][1]
```

I'm running this one one machine both acting as a hub and a node just to make a proof of concept it'll work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it solved, used the appropriate version IEDriver and fixed the PATH and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things I'd question about your approach to what you're trying to accomplish. First, if you're running your C# code on the same machine as the remote Java server (node/hub), why bother? You can easily just use the `InternetExplorerDriver` class and eliminate the Java server altogether.

Second, setting an environment variable is **not** the same as setting a Java system property. You can set the system property by using a `-D` command line flag on the command line with which you launch the Java .jar.

Finally, if you're actually running the Java server on a different machine from the C# code, and are correctly using `RemoteWebDriver`, bear in mind that you need `IEDriverServer.exe` on the machine running the Java server, and not the one running your C# code. Furthermore, you need the hub/node to be aware of the path to the executable on that machine, not to the executable where your C# code is running.

Comment: Hi Jim, and thanks on the answer.
Yes this is the C# binding, and I'm running everything on one machine just to make a proof of concept that It'll work for me.